# Spring Batch Retry NEVER retries with simple XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We have a spring batch application developed 2 years back using the old style of XML configuration built using gradle. Simple setup added the job with retries for a custom runtime exception. We don't have the intention to migrate this application to latest annotation based configs as it is running in production now.

Recently discovered that retry is not at all working for some mysterious reason. I tried to upgrade the Spring batch versions locally to the latest but its not helping. Discovered this initially at one of the step calling a @Service class to fetch some data in the @PostContruct, thought it was because of @PostContruct, created an additional step using a Tasklet and tried. I tried all options, the latest change is just tried to throw an java.lang.Exception directly but does not work. Tried @Retryable at the class and method level, never worked, Now I started to wonder, would this retry ever works? I'm giving up on this but desperately needed some help. Anybody who can provide clue or solution to solve this problem would be my Hero! Thank you!

Some code section(Groovy code, some unnecessary Java syntax never used) here(I have cut short some of the methods to show the actual area of concern, but feel free to ask for more config changes) -

```
dependencies {

    testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3"
    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-groovy:${cukes.version}"
    testCompile "info.cukes:cucumber-junit:${cukes.version}"
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.11"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:${spock.version}"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-spring:${spock.version}"

    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:${groovy.version}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-test:${spring.version}"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-core:${spring.version}"
    compile "org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:4.0.1.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:4.0.1.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.2.2.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test:4.0.1.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.9.0.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:1.9.0.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:${spring.version}"
    ...
    }

<batch:job id="facebookPermissionsReminderEmailJob" restartable="true">

    <batch:step id="businessPageProcess" parent="faultTolerance" next="facebookPermissionsReminderEmailStep">
        <tasklet ref="businessPageProcessor" retry-limit="5">
            <retryable-exception-classes>
                <include class="java.lang.Exception"/>
                <include class="com.reachlocal.data.synchronizer.model.ApiException"/>
            </retryable-exception-classes>

            <batch:retry-listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="retryLoggerListener" />
            </batch:retry-listeners>

        </tasklet>
    </batch:step>

<bean id="faultTolerance" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantStepFactoryBean" abstract="true">
  <property name="backOffPolicy">
    <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
        <property name="initialInterval" value="180000" />
        <property name="multiplier" value="2" />
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>

@Slf4j
@Scope("step")
@Component("businessPageProcessor")
class BusinessPageProcessor implements Tasklet {

@Autowired
BusinessPagesService businessPagesService

@Autowired
PermissionReminderDetails reminderDetails

Map<String, BusinessPage> nameToPageMap = [:]
Date currentDate

@Override
RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {

    log.info("Inside FacebookFirstReminderProcessor.initProcessorDetails() - retrieving facebook Business info")
    List<BusinessPage> businessPages = businessPagesService.getAll()
    log.info("Business Pages info retrieved from facebook: ${businessPages}")

    businessPages.forEach({ page ->
        String pageUrl = extractPageName(page.link ? page.link : page.pageResponse?.link)
        nameToPageMap.put(pageUrl, page)
    })
    log.info("Generated Page to Status Map is: ${nameToPageMap}")

    currentDate = new Date()
    log.info("--------DATE-------- : run date is ${currentDate} for current batch process")

    reminderDetails.currentDate = this.currentDate
    reminderDetails.nameToPageMap = this.nameToPageMap


    RepeatStatus.FINISHED

}

}

@Service
class BusinessPagesService {

@Autowired
PlatformProperty platformProperty

@Autowired
ApiCaller apiCaller

List<BusinessPage> getAll() {
    String businessId = platformProperty.facebookReachLocalBusinessId
    getAll(businessId)
}
List<BusinessPage> getAll(String businessId) {
    List<BusinessPage> businessPages = []
    Assert.isTrue(StringUtils.isNotBlank(businessId), EMPTY_BUSINESS_ID_ERROR_MESSAGE)

    String approvedPagesEndPoint = enrichApiUrlForGetApprovedPages(businessId)
    String pendingPagesEndPoint  = enrichApiUrlForGetPendingPages(businessId)

    List<BusinessPage> approvedPages = getBusinessPages(businessId, approvedPagesEndPoint)
    //FB does not return access info, so manually setting the value for rest of the workflow logic to work as it is.
    approvedPages.stream().forEach({page -> page.accessStatus = FacebookPageAccessStatus.CONFIRMED})

    List<BusinessPage> pendingPages = getBusinessPages(businessId, pendingPagesEndPoint)
    //FB does not return access info, so manually setting the value for rest of the workflow logic to work as it is.
    pendingPages.stream().forEach({page -> page.accessStatus = FacebookPageAccessStatus.PENDING})

    businessPages.addAll(approvedPages)
    businessPages.addAll(pendingPages)
    businessPages

}

List<BusinessPage> getBusinessPages(String businessId, String endPointUrl) {
    List<BusinessPage> businessPages = []
    while (true) {
        log.info("Retrieving Business Pages details for Business Id of: ${businessId} using enriched URL of: ${endPointUrl}")

        BusinessPagesResponse response = getSubSetOfBusinessPages(endPointUrl)
        log.info("Successfully retrieve Business Pages details ${response}")

        if(response.businessPages) {
            businessPages.addAll(response.businessPages)
            endPointUrl = response.paging?.next
        } else {
            break
        }
        if (!endPointUrl) {
            break
        }
    }
    businessPages

}
BusinessPagesResponse getSubSetOfBusinessPages (String endPointURL) {
    BusinessPagesResponse response
    try {
        response = (BusinessPagesResponse) apiCaller.call(
                endPointURL,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<BusinessPagesResponse>() {},
                Optional.empty(),
                HttpMethod.GET)
        throw new Exception("Test Exception")
        //log.info("Successfully retrieve Business Pages details ${response}")
    } catch (ApiException apiEx){
        if (apiEx.message.contains(EXCESS_DATA_REQUESTED_FAILURE_TEXT)) {
            log.error("ExcessDataRequestedException occurred - retrying")
            String exceptionClass = apiEx.class.name.concat("-")
            throw new Exception(exceptionClass.concat(apiEx.message)) // will trigger retry upto defined max.
        } else {
            throw apiEx
        }
    }
    //response
}

@Component
class RetryLoggerListener extends RetryListenerSupport  {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass())

@Override
<T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback,Throwable throwable) {
    logger.error("Error occurred during operation {}",throwable.getMessage())
}
}
```

Comment: Retry on a Tasklet is not supported out of the box via Spring Batch.  You'd need to use the Spring Retry functionality natively for that to work.

Comment: I tried initially for the chuck processing, and then I moved the logic to tasklet to see if it works, thats what I updated here, but in either case it does not work out of box with those configuration, I turned on the Spring batch debug logs to find out whats going on, I could see some retry attempts were made but later failed and it was hard to debug the framework classes. I believe this used to work long time back and now its stopped, not sure because of so many library upgrades. I could see some google search results saying it works just like that, not sure whats conflicting in my case.